# Autolayout - pull apart super view?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, autolayout

Is it possible to set height of super view relying on summarized height and padding between its child elements using auto layout?

Basically I'm trying to fill subviews with text from remote server, views are changing height dynamically, but their superview (or container view in other words) is static.

Answer (score 1):

See [-intrinsicContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW177) and -invalidateIntrinsicContentSize. I believe this alone will get you there in simple cases. As I understand it, other things (including superviews with constrained distance from edges of a subview) will be moved to accommodate a view that claims a minimum size that would break those other constraints (keeping your view visible, for example).

I'd love it if others would chime in to validate/invalidate/correct me here. I'm still wrapping my own head around the many details specific to Autolayout in practice.